# Mounting a drive in debian from php code

Tags: php, linux, apache, debian, mount

I've been at this for two days now and haven't been able to find any way (good or bad) of doing that to work.

I have to be able of dynamically mounting drives over network from my website's pages (that part is inevitable).

I have no problems doing it directly on the console with the following command

```
mount -t cifs //IP-REMOTE-MACHINE/Folder -o username=username,password=password /mnt/share
```

Obviously trying to just do a `shell_exec()` of this command wouldn't work with no root rights.

I tried to `shell_exec()` a script in which I would switch to root user (via su or sudo mycommand) but both of them wouldn't work (never been able to succeed in doing a script who would automatically switch my user to root even with the root pwd hard coded (even if that feels an extremely bad idea I could have accepted that atm).

After that I tried to use `pmount`but never found a way to access to a remote shared file (don't think it's even possible but I may have missed something here?)

All that is running on a Debian machine with apache2.

Comment: How did it not work? Add some detail here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a wild idea...

You could set a cron to run as root that checks for mount commands from your script. The script would simply set a mount command to be processed, and when the cron gets to it, runs the mount, marks the command as processed, and writes to a log file which you could then display.

Comment: Actually that's a very good idea, since I have to move files around anyway it would take too long (sometimes) managing that via php, I'll do it with cron.

Answer (score 0):

It's not safe to run sudo commands with www-data (the user for web servers in Debian).

But if you want to run sudo [command] in a php script, you must add the user www-data in sudoers: http://www.pendrivelinux.com/how-to-add-a-user-to-the-sudoers-list/

And then you can exec: `sudo mount ...`

EDIT: It's safer to add in visudo:

```
www-data ALL= NOPASSWD: /bin/mount
```

To allow www-data to use only `sudo /bin/mount`

Comment: Yes I have seen this option but that seemed even worst than the script who would automatically switch from www-data to root so I hoped finding something more "clean" (but if I don't find anything else I might come to that option)

Comment: You can add the command to allow the execution of ONLY this command:
www-data ALL= NOPASSWD: /bin/mount